Parsing csv file output before certain date
I am trying to sort and parse lines in a csv file. So far I have been able to sort the date column. Assuming I can use sort to filter from a certain date - but all the info I find deals with different date formats.  Below is a sample of the file.
Here is how I have sorted the output by date so far:
sort -t, -k 3 timestamp.csv | grep @example.com

user1@example.com,active,20240716084550.486Z
brismith@example.com,active,20240716084558.413Z
bnuser5@example.com,active,20240716084608.601Z
he8776@example.com,active,20240716084619.079Z
rd88377@example.com,active,20240716084626.169Z
britest@example.com,active,20240716084652.013Z

I would like to sort the output with all lines with a date string of "20240418" and before that date.
I tired sorting the output by the date column with:
sort -t, -k 3 timestamp.csv | grep @example.com

I am expecting to show output with a date column of 20240418 or before this date. I can just edit the file manually (what works for now) but would like to parse the file from the cli to save a step.
Thank you

"sort the date row" -- don't you mean date column?

does your final result require the data to be sorted by the 3rd column? or are you sorting the data solely as a means of finding the rows before/after '20240418'?

generally speaking you should consider providing sample data with a few rows that match your requirement and a few rows that don't match your requirement, then also include the expected result; we currently have 6 rows from '20240716' and a search requirement for everything on/before '20240418' so, basically, none of your input data matches the search requirement

with a date string of "20240418" and before that date. - please confirm if the time of day is to be ignored in the comparison; in other words, should everything between (and including) 20240418000000.000Z and 20240418235959.999Z  be included in the output?

Sorry, edited. My brain is half working apparently today.

Yes, time of day can be ignored. The goal of this is to filter to only stale accounts that have not logged in since 20240418000000 as an example.

After sorting, pipe to awk and exit when you get a line higher than your target date.
sort -t, -k 3 timestamp.csv | awk -F, '$3 > 20240418000000 {exit} /@example.com/'


Thank you Barmar. I didn't think of using awk, you are a life saver.

I wonder if ordering the pipeline awk  -F, '$3 > 20240418000000 && $1 ~ /@example.com/' file | sort -t, -k3 might be quicker

Oddly enough, I get a different total of lines with that order, from the same file:
$ sort -t, -k 3 sorted.csv | awk -F, '$3 > 20240418000000 {exit} /@example.com/' | wc -l
3941
$ awk  -F, '$3 > 20240418000000 && $1 ~ /@example.com/' sorted.csv | sort -t, -k3 | wc -l
8216

Try using the -n option to sort.

@dj423 your output is different because the second script's condition is the opposite of the first. In the second script $3 > 20240418000000 should be $3 <= 20240418000000 since you said you want "to show output with a date column of 20240418 or before this date". You don't need all the 0s at the end of the number, btw as awk will do a string comparison anyway since the input value is a string, not a number.

@EdMorton It does numeric comparison if you compare with a number. I'd have to write $3 > "20240418"

@Barmar awk would only do a numeric comparison if the input value from $3 looked like a number (and so was considered a "strnum" or "numeric string") but since it ends with a letter (Z) it doesn't look like a number and so you have an input string being compared against a literal number and so awk will do a string comparison given it's string vs number.
